# Error in forwarding an email

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Sub ForwardEmail(item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oMail As MailItem

On Error GoTo Release

If item.Class = olMail Then
    Set oMail = item.Forward
    oMail.Subject = oMail.Subject
    oMail.HTMLBody = "Have a good day." & vbCrLf & oMail.HTMLBody
    oMail.Recipients.Add "abc@xyz.com"
End If

Release:
Set oMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hi, I am trying to forward an email from outlook using vba in excel. I am getting an error in the line   **Set oMail = item.Forward**. I see an outlook window but then it also gives an error saying "Application defined or object defined error" .

I am able to compose an email using vba but not forward. I see an forward window but the code stops on the line above and I am not able to add subject and other things.

Thanks.

Comment: 1 - When debugging comment out On Error lines. 2 - Where does item come from?

Comment: Something is weird here - how can you be seeing the window for the forwarded item with calling oMail.Display??

Comment: Are you sure that you have passed an item to the procedure?  And Eric is correct, you shouldn't see a window if you haven't used the Display method.

Comment: @EricLegault yes, it is wierd because the same thing was working some months back and i didn't have any problem. The window opens without me having used the display method. Also the item comes from searching my mail box by a subject and then forwarding that item. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you only need the lines of code in that procedure starting with Set oMail - the Class check is redundant as anything but a MailItem param will throw an error in the calling procedure.

Comment: When you say - **"using vba in excel"**, are you running the code in Excel?

Comment: That's just something I found:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458119%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Maybe this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try disable error handlers while debugging code.

MSDN  [Turning Off Error Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231191%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Option Explicit
Sub ForwardEmail(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    If olItem.class = olMail Then
        '// Forward Email
        Set olItem = olItem.Forward
        '// Append The Subject
        olItem.Subject = "BlaBla " & olItem.Subject
        '//  Add Recipient
        olItem.Recipients.Add "Om3r <i@me.com>"
        '// add msg
        olItem.HTMLBody = "Have a good day" + olItem.HTMLBody
        '// Dispaly or use .Send
        olItem.Display
'        olItem.Send
    End If
End Sub
```